# Why does Windows 10 OpenSSH not allow me to connect to my local ssh server with error connection reset

Tags: windows, ssh

(**Update** I managed to solve this by switching on the VPN to the company I work for. The ssh server is running on my laptop. I work from home.)

I followed these instructions to set up SSH server on Windows 10 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

I am getting this error message when logging in to the server (verbose log near the bottom). Any ideas?

```
Connection reset by xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx%18 port 22
```

I installed OpenSSH client and server

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False


Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

Path          :
Online        : True
```

I started the service

```
Start-Service sshd
```

Checked the firewall setting is there

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*

Name                  : OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP
DisplayName           : OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
Description           : Inbound rule for OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
DisplayGroup          : OpenSSH Server
Group                 : OpenSSH Server
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

RestartNeeded : False
```

Then attempted to log in

```
Ssh user.name@hostname
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx%18' to the list of known hosts.
Connection reset by xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx%18 port 22
```

Here is the verbose log

```
Ssh -v user.name@hostname
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to hostname [xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx%18] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to hostname:22 as 'user.name'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:6MokRsZL9FrzHEjHvVmqPrmIQj1wf6XaSjqgJBuK3cg
debug1: Host 'hostname' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user.name/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection reset by xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx%18 port 22
```